# Should we clean target folder after tests

Tags: java

I am wondering if we should clean target folder after tests for instance deleting files that where created in test. If target folder is not under version control is it necessary to clean target folder? What is a convention?

Thanks

Comment: That really depends on the scenario..

Comment: Do you have a maven project?

Comment: If your target-folder only created for a test and never been used after this test - then i would clear and delete it. If you need information on later usage out of this folder and your test are created files with unique-.date or id-stamps than it depends on your feeling if you copy the needed data to another folder or let this target folder alive.

Comment: After the test is done there should be a cleanup namely @AfterClass in junit. After this method all the data should be the same as before the test invocation. If you are testing properly its not necessery to clean your target

Comment: What do you mean by "target folder" ? the folder with your results or the maven target folder ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you clean them before/after the test. I had a maven project with different environment profiles. For unit test, I used the local/testing profile, and when I deployed the project to my alpha environment which used the alpha profile, there are some files which only for unit test were deployed. so, I always do cleanup before build and test now.